# Picking a random Key and Value from a Map?

Tags: java

Here's a seemingly trivial coding task that I just can't seem to find an elegant solution for. Perhaps it's a Sunday afternoon 'dumbness' thing but I'm just not seeing it.

I have a Map that represents a set of names for a group:

```
  1. Map<String, Set<String>> namesForGroup;
```

With content that looks something like this:

```
1 {"Grp1": {"a", "b", "c", "d"},
2 "Grp2": {"e", "f", "g", "h"}}
```

What I'd like is an elegant way to extract a random Key Value pair from that Map. For example:

```
1 ["Grp1", "a"]
2 ["Grp1", "d"]
3 ["Grp2", "g"]
4 ["Grp1", "c"]
5 ["Grp2", "e"]
```

There is no requirement for any strong randomness or any even distribution of the chosen values. A rough approximation is all that is required as I'm just generating some test data for a performance benchmark I'm writing for a new feature I've written at work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: I noticed you have unaccepted the answer. Were there any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Getting random elements from a set is a bit more complicated than getting random elements from a list, but here's how it would work:

```
private static String[] getRandomPair(Map<String, Set<String>> map) {
    Random random = new Random();

    String[] groups = map.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    String randomGroup = groups[random.nextInt(groups.length)];

    String[] names = map.get(randomGroup).toArray(new String[0]);
    String randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];

    return new String[] { randomGroup, randomName };
}
```

Sample use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> namesForGroup = new HashMap<>();
    namesForGroup.put("Grp1", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d")));
    namesForGroup.put("Grp2", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("e", "f", "g", "h")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandomPair(namesForGroup)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandomPair(namesForGroup)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandomPair(namesForGroup)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandomPair(namesForGroup)));
}
```

Prints e.g.:

```
[Grp2, e]
[Grp1, a]
[Grp2, e]
[Grp1, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate of a few others, sort of.  It is perhaps unique from the duplicate links in that you need to find a random element of a set, twice, in a nested fashion.  You can take a random map entry from your map's entry set, grab that key, and then take a random element from that entry's value, which itself is another set.

To do this, it might help if we create a helper method which can find a random element in a Java `Set`.  This is needed because sets are inherently *unordered*.  We can't just access some index, because there isn't one (well, maybe in `TreeSet` this might make sense, but not in a regular `Set`).

```
public static < T > T getRandomSetEntry(Set<T> set) {
    int size = set.size();
    int item = new Random().nextInt(size);
    int i = 0;
    for (T obj : set) {
        if (i == item)
            return obj;
        i++;
    }

    return null;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> namesForGroup = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add("a");
    set1.add("b");
    set1.add("c");
    set1.add("d");
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set2.add("e");
    set2.add("f");
    set2.add("g");
    set2.add("h");

    namesForGroup.put("Grp1", set1);
    namesForGroup.put("Grp2", set2);

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>> set = namesForGroup.entrySet();
    Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry = getRandomSetEntry(set);
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = getRandomSetEntry(entry.getValue());
    System.out.println("key: " + key + ", value: " + value);
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester